# PHP add thousands separator to sum total

Tags: php, separator

I have a PHP script that displays the sum total from a database column. The output shows as `123456`. How would I add a thousands separator so it will display as `123,456`?

I have tried variations of using $english below without much success:

```
$english_format_number = number_format($number);
```

The exact script below - appreciate if someone can show me exactly how to add this:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <span><?php echo $count["polls"] ?></span> <?php echo e("Polls created successfully.") ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a syntax error in your code (an extraneous `e` in your second statement). `number_format()` should work fine for you. Perhaps you were just assigning the value of `number_format($count['polls']))` to a variable and forgetting to actually use `echo`. Regardless, this should be what you're looking for:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <span><?php echo number_format($count["polls"]); ?></span> <?php echo "Polls created successfully."; ?>
</div>
```

Does that work? If not, what happens?

Comment: Please don't ask questions as answers! Use comments for clarification.

Comment: OP already said that he tried it with `number_format()` so, you just ask here what OP gets for results for this code, in my opinion that's not a proper answer. For me it seems more like: Try this or try this

Comment: @Leo What? I thought you said that you tried it this way?!

Comment: @Rizier123 OP didn't mention whether or not he was actually echoing the value of `number_format()`; his code only showed an assignment, and my answer actually printed the value. I think my answer added something. I appreciate your point, though.

Comment: @ChrisBrendel okay, I will just leave it. Just out of interest: Where is OP missing semicolons? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Rizier123 Apologies, my mistake. I never do PHP inline and didn't realize that the last statement is valid without a semicolon. Fixed. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion - I tried using a variation of the $english_format_number but obviously had not added it correctly. Chris answer of exactly how to use this in my script solved it. Thanks again to Chris and everyone and my apologies on the confusion.